# Using PHP to download BLOB on iOS

Tags: php, blob

I have a quite simple and straight forward question to do.
I need to download 3 different types of data from my MySQL server:

: Image, Audio, Video

So I was going across some deep PHP things and I found these two pieces of code:

AUDIO:

```
<?php
    // Connect to database
    @mysql_connect("mysql.server.com.br","user","pass01");
    @mysql_select_db("database01") or die( "Unable to select database");

    // Find out about latest image

    $gotten = @mysql_query("SELECT audio_content AS audio_in_blob FROM database01.audio_content WHERE content_id = 'id01';");
    if ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($gotten)) {
        $bytes = $row[ "audio_in_blob" ];
    } 
    else {
        echo "hoe!";
        $errmsg = 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        $title = "no database image available";
    }

    // If this is the image request, send out the image

    header("Content-type: audio/mp3");
    echo $bytes;
    exit ();
?>
```

VIDEO:

```
<?php

    // Connect to database

    @mysql_connect("mysql.server.com.br","user","pass01");
    @mysql_select_db("database01") or die( "Unable to select database");

    // Find out about latest image

    $gotten = @mysql_query("SELECT video_content AS video_in_blob FROM database01.video_content WHERE content_id = 'id01';");
    if ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($gotten)) {
        $bytes = $row[ "video_in_blob" ];
    } 
    else {
        echo "hoe!";
        $errmsg = 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        $title = "no database image available";
    }

    // If this is the image request, send out the image

    header("Content-type: video/mpeg");
    echo $bytes;
    exit ();
?>
```

But these methods they only sort of display the blob in browser and don't download them.
What can i do? I need to download these blobs and make the usable for video/photo/audio display.

Cheers.

Comment: What about this has to do with iOS?

Comment: Do not quite understand your problem. But I believe it to run on iOS you need the tag `<video>` HTML5. I have an iphone, if you have a link for me to test.

Comment: Well, i just need to download the video/audio/image from a BLOB thats the point.